# How to find a parameter combination for a black box using AI?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, ai-design, regression, algorithm-request

I am working on a project where I encountered a component which takes 96 arguments (all integer values) and outputs 12 float values.
I would like to find a useful combination of these 96 values to receive the output that I want while avoiding random guessing, so the desired behavior would be that I provide the outcome and receive the 96 inputs to use them in my component.

Unfortunately I am not that experienced in that field. If I think about how I can implement this, my first thought was a kind of classification task, since I could build a dataset but the problem here is that I need integer values.

A second guess was a regression but would that be possible for y as an output vector?
Are there some other approaches that could fit to my use case?

Comment: "would that be possible for y as an output vector?": please, could you clarify this phrase ?

Comment: I‘m sorry, I was talking about multi-output regression but in this case I would have 96 output values and I was wondering if this could yield any useful result.